# Is Alexandroff Duplicate normal?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be any topological space and let $A(X)= X\cup X'$ be its Alexandroff Duplicate. If $X$ is normal, is $A(X)$ also normal?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: X prime= X union {1}

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if $X$ is a normal space, then $A(X)$ is also normal.

I will consider the underlying set of $A(X)$ to be $X \times \{ 0 , 1 \}$, topologised by declaring the basic open sets to be of the following form:

1. $(U \times \{ 0 , 1 \}) \setminus ( A \times \{ 1 \})$ where $U \subseteq X$ is open and $A \subseteq X$ is finite;
2. $\{ \langle x , 1 \rangle \}$ for $x \in X$.

It follows that any subset of $X \times \{ 1 \}$ open in $A(X)$, and $X \times \{ 0 \}$ is a closed subspace of $A(X)$ which is homeomorphic to $X$. For notational ease, given any $B \subseteq A(X)$ denote

- $B_0 = \{ x \in X : \langle x , 0 \rangle \in B \}$;
- $B_1 = \{ x \in X : \langle x , 1 \rangle \in B \}$.

Suppose that $F,E$ are disjoint closed subsets of $A(X)$.  Then $F_0$, $E_0$ are disjoint closed subsets of $X$. By normality of $X$ there are disjoint open $U^\prime,V^\prime \subseteq X$ such that $F_0 \subseteq U^\prime$, $E_0 \subseteq V^\prime$.  Then $U = U^\prime \times \{ 0 , 1 \}$, $V = V^\prime \times \{ 0 ,1 \}$ are disjoint open subsets of $A(X)$. It is now easy to show that $$( U \cup F ) \setminus E = ( U \cup ( F_1 \times \{ 1 \} ) ) \setminus E; \\ ( V \cup E ) \setminus F = ( V \cup ( E_1 \times \{ 1 \} ) ) \setminus F$$ are disjoint open subsets of $A(X)$ including $F,E$, respectively.

Comment: hmm, yes because $X\times \{0\}$ is a closed subspace considering $A(X)$ as the topology on $X\times \{0,1\}$ can be justified because a closed subspace of a normal is normal. btw still vague. a new notation could be clearer.