# Describe all compact subspace .

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a space and consider its Alexandroff Duplicate $A(X)$. How can I describe all compact subspaces of $A(X)$. 
The following statement does not work with me: " prove that $C$ is compact if and only if ($C\cap X$) is compact in $X$ and the set ($C \cap X'$)\ ($C \cap X$ )$'$ is finite. Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you mean, it doesn't work for me? It seems like the correct statement. Have you tried to prove it?

Comment: I mean I can not prove that the set ( C intersection X')\ ( C intersection X )' is finite.

Comment: Remember that each point in $X^\prime$ is isolated.

Comment: I know that,how can I benefit from that to proof it is finite?

Comment: Actually, there is something to think about here. Do you assume that the original space $X$ satisfies any separation axioms?

Comment: We do not assume any separation axiom.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of a half-answer.  I'll again keep to the notation I set up in a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/741188/8348).  Additionally, given $B \subseteq A(X) = X \times \{ 0 , 1 \}$ for $i = 0,1$ I will denote $$B_i = \{ x \in X : \langle x , i \rangle \in B \}.$$

It is fairly easy to show that if $C \subseteq A(X)$ is such that

- $C_0 := \{ x \in X : \langle x,0 \rangle \in C \}$ is a compact subset of $X$; and
- $C_1 \setminus C_0$ is finite

then $C$ is a compact subset of $A(X)$.  (Begin with an open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $C$ by basic open sets

However not all compact subsets of $A(X)$ are of this form.  For an example, consider the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, and the following subset of $A(\mathbb{R})$: $$C = ( [0,1] \times \{ 0 , 1 \} ) \cup ( \{ \tfrac{-1}{n} : n \geq 1 \} \times \{ 1 \} ).$$  Note that $C_0 = [0,1]$ and $C_1 = [0,1] \cup \{ \frac{-1}{n} : n \geq 1 \}$, meaning that $C_1 \setminus  C_0 = \{ \frac{-1}{n} : n \geq 1 \}$ is infinite.  However it is straightforward (if a little tedious) to show that $C$ is compact.  (The key idea is that any open $U \subseteq A(\mathbb{R})$ containing $\langle 0,0 \rangle$ must also contain all but finitely many of the $\frac{-1}{n}$ ($n \geq 1$), and so if you have a finitely many open subsets $U^1 , \ldots , U^n$ of $A(X)$ covering $C_0 \times \{ 0 \}$, and $C \setminus U^1 \cup \cdots \cup U^n$ is finite.)

This leads to a proper characterisation of the compact subsets of $A(X)$:

> $C \subseteq A(X)$ is compact iff
>
> - $C_0$ is a compact subset of $X$; and
> - given any open $U \subseteq X$ including $C_0$, the set $C_1 \setminus U$ is finite.

Comment: (I am uncertain whether this characterisation can be simplified.)